# C# SQL Server stored procedure not returning expected value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I wrote up this function to return a dataset, I was expecting a smaller dataset as there's only one value I was expecting back, but I get a rather bloated object back which I cannot find the value I am looking for, this is causing problems as I intend to use this function heavily.

I was hoping someone could spot what I am doing wrong, I have included the code, a screenshot of the returned object and what I am expecting. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If I have not phrased anything in this question correctly feel free to let me know, I struggle to express my thoughts well.

```
public DataSet getPartnerParameter(string parameter)
{
    using (var dbConnection = new SqlConnection(UnityHelper.IocContainer.Resolve<IConfigHelperService>().GetConnectionString("CASConnectionString")))
    {
        dbConnection.Open();

        using (var dbCommand = new SqlCommand("GETPARTNERPARAMETER"))
        {
            dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            dbCommand.Connection = dbConnection;

            SqlParameter lstrParameter = new SqlParameter("@Parameter", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            lstrParameter.Value = parameter;
            dbCommand.Parameters.Add(lstrParameter);

            var ldaDPS = new SqlDataAdapter(dbCommand);
            var ldstParameterValues = new DataSet();
            ldaDPS.Fill(ldstParameterValues);

            return ldstParameterValues;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: data object contents]

This is what I am expecting to find

[image: Execute stored procedure]

edit//

changed my code slightly but still not working.

```
public String[] getPartnerParameter(string parameter)
{
    using (var dbConnection = new SqlConnection(UnityHelper.IocContainer.Resolve<IConfigHelperService>().GetConnectionString("CASConnectionString")))
    {
        dbConnection.Open();

        SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand("GETPARTNERPARAMETER", dbConnection);
        dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter lstrParameter = new SqlParameter("@Parameter", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        lstrParameter.Value = parameter;
        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(lstrParameter);

        SqlDataReader reader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();
        string[] results = new string[2];
        while (reader.Read())
        {

            results[0] = reader[0].ToString();
            results[1] = reader[1].ToString();
    
        }
        if (results.Length < 1)
        {
            results[0] = "Cannot find Value";
            results[1] = "S";
            return results;
        }
        else
        {

            return results;
        }
    }
```

The error is this:
{"Procedure or function 'GETPARTNERPARAMETER' expects parameter '@Parameter', which was not supplied."}

Comment: Stored procedures don't return objects. Your code doesn't execute the stored procedure directly, it used an Adapter to fill a Dataset from it. What object are you talking about? What did you expect to get? Why load a Dataset anyway? Did you copy the code from some old example perhaps?

Comment: If the stored procedure returns a single value you can use `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar` to return it directly. To return multiple fields and rows you need `ExecuteReader` so you can read the rows one by one. That's what the adapter does to load the DataSet's tables. You can get rid of it though, and fill a DataTable directly with `DataTable.Load(IDbDataReader)`.

Comment: i copied the method from how others have done this within the same codebase as i wanted to try keep an element of consistency but as the other segments have been specialised i had to change this else i would of just made into a function to remove repeated code.#

Comment: Perhaps an even better idea is to use a micro-ORM like Dapper and get the results automatically mapped to objects, eg `connection.Query<MyRecord>(sprocName);` will execute the stored procedure and map the results to `MyRecord` instances based on property names

Comment: That's **not** a common way to load data. That's **very old code** - think pre-2005, that gets blindly copied around. Nobody wants to create DataSet instances without reason

Comment: funny enough this project is very old ^^

Comment: You can replace all this with a single line using Dapper, returning a single record shaped the way you want now.

Comment: i am intrigued i will look up dapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values you are looking for are probably in the dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0] row.

However, if you are expecting one row back, a DataSet object seems like overkill.  I would recommend avoiding the SqlDataAdapter/DataSet and instead use a SqlDataReader.

Untested code, but should give you the gist of how to use it:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand("GETPARTNERPARAMETER", connection);
    dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlParameter lstrParameter = new SqlParameter("@Parameter", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    lstrParameter.Value = "LexisNexisCreditConsentRequired";
    dbCommand.Parameters.Add(lstrParameter);

    SqlDataReader reader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var yourValue = reader[0];
        var yourDataType = reader[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: @DStanley true, if he wants a single value back.  From the question it looks like he is expecting a row back.

Comment: Ahh I missed that and read it as a single value. Thanks.

Comment: I get this error, i updated my question to show the code i am using taken from what you have said.
{"Procedure or function 'GETPARTNERPARAMETER' expects parameter '@Parameter', which was not supplied."}

Comment: Hard to say, it looks right from the C# side and you are providing the @Parameter param.  I would double check to make sure you are running your code correctly (has it been rebuilt?) and that the value is not NULL.  Also might want to post the stored procedure declaration & argument list.

Comment: Actually you might need to add "dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;" when building the command

Comment: this this made it compile past the dbcommand.executereader(); However now i am getting "Enumeration yielded no results"

Comment: It sounds like the command is completing, now it's just not returning any data, which is a separate issue.  To confirm this, I would run the stored procedure directly in SSMS to verify the results, then look at the stored procedure code & the data to diagnose why

Comment: i have included a picture of me running the sproc directly in ssms in my original question. i do appreciate the help.

Comment: Check the stored procedure by running "sp_helptext GETPARTNERPARAMETER" in SSMS.  It might be that the parameter name is incorrect.

Comment: Sorry for lack of reply i am still working on this however we are migrating from tfs source control to git which isnt easy when i get my work machine working again i will come back to this. Although i leave the company in a week for a new role so even that isnt certain. So thank you for the help so far if i dont get chance to come back to this.

Comment: your solution works there was a bug in my stored procedure thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A `DataSet` is an object which can contain many tables. It doesn't have to, but it can, and so it also has a number of fields, properties, and methods to support that role.

For this query, look at `ldstParameterValues.Tables[0].Rows[0]`. Within that row, you can also see the columns with another level of bracket-indexing:

```
DataRow row = ldstParameterValues.Tables[0].Rows[0];
var column0Value row[0];
var column1Value = row[1];
```

However, the type for these results is **object**. You'll need to either cast the values or use one of the `GetX()` methods on the datarow to get results with a meaningful type.